# What temperature can Endure Elements withstand?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, dnd-3e

The D&D spell *Endure Elements* can prevent five hit points per round of damage. What temperature range does that correspond to in both directions? That is, how cold an ambient temperature does it take to cause five hit points of frost damage per round, and how hot an ambient temperature does it take to cause five hit points of fire damage per round?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>You've mixed up two different spells. *[Endure elements](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/endureElements.htm)* can keep you comfortable in temperatures between -50°F and -140°F, but prevents no hit point damage. It's [*resist energy*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/resistEnergy.htm) (and the more potent [*protection from energy*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/protectionFromEnergy.htm)) that stops damage from fire and frost.</s>

The above is, naturally, true in 3.5. In 3.0, [the spell's description](http://www.dragon.ee/30srd/spellse.htm) says that it only prevents damage, and doesn't prevent "unfortunate side effects." However, we also can turn to the environmental damage rules, which say that temperatures above 90°F can inflict 1d4 subdual damage, and that those below 40°F can inflict 1d6 subdual damage on a failed save. Those could be considered "fire" and "frost" damage of a sort.

Comment: Ah, that's the 3.5 version you're thinking of? I'm thinking of 3.0 as per the tag.

Comment: So noted! Let me change that answer.

Comment: And for those of us *not* using Fahrenheit (officially the whole world except for the United States, Cayman Islands and Belize, afaik :)), 90°F is about 32,3°C whereas 40°F corresponds to 4,4°C.

Comment: @OpaCitiZen I'm just quoting the SRD. Perhaps Celsius temperatures are product identity. :)